# Jenkins windows ssh slave access denied

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to build  my projects on a Windows machine, so I created a slave there. First we tried the standard java application runner, but our build sets up its own environment and it always ended up deleting the existing Java installation, not giving any proper error messages, but failing. Then I switched to using Cygwin sshd and have Jenkins log in via ssh. This works for the connection (just as the standard method worked), but when I ran the build then it failed again to install the jdk. I ended up running the following command by hand:

```
C:\jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\Latest\jdk.exe ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR=C:\jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\Latest /L
```

This is the same as Jenkins would run, but without the /s (silent) option. Now when I run the build, I get the following error:

```
    Building remotely on jenkins-slave-win64 (Johnny5) (windows) in workspace C:\jenkins\workspace\continuous.xill
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: C:\jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\Latest at hudson.remoting.Channel@200354fa:jenkins-slave-win64 (Johnny5): java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\Latest\bin\java.exe
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:987)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:1171)
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.performInstallation(JDKInstaller.java:130)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:108)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:132)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:360)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2234)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:935)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1036)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1277)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\Latest\bin\java.exe
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:247)
```

Of course I tried everything:

Run sshd as a different (Administrator) user
Checked every error mentioned here:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+slaves+and+Cygwin

here

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/My+software+builds+on+my+computer+but+not+on+Jenkins

and here

- http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html

And nothing works. Do you have a hint where to look?

UPDATE:

Meanwhile I managed to get a bit further in the build process by deactivating the option to "Automatically install jdk" in the Jenkins settings, git clone works and gradle starts up. However, now the JAVA_HOME environment variable somehow is not accessible to the slave (although we even tried setting it in .bashrc, just to be sure). So the build fails with this message":

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'http://dl.bintray.com/content/shemnon/javafx-gradle/8.1.1/javafx.plugin' line: 60

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find JavaFX Packager Tools, please set one of [jfxrtDir in Gradle Properties, JFXRT_HOME in System Environment, JAVA_HOME in System Environment, java.home in JVM properties]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your build error after "UPDATE" I think you have to add a JDK under Manage Jenkins > Configure System > JDK or in newer versions under Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > JDK